# Problem with \hline and reference

Tags: tables, cross-referencing, rules

I am trying to end my table with a `\hline`.

My tex is as follows

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ l | c || r }
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline
4 & 5 & 6 \\ \hline
7 & 8 & 9 \\
\hline
\caption{ Result }
\label{tab:a}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

However the resultant image is as follows:

[image]

As you can see an empty row gets added below the end. Can somebody tell me how to correct it?

Comment: Now you can upvote `;-)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\caption` and `\label` must be placed *outside* the `tabular` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ l | c || r }
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline
4 & 5 & 6 \\ \hline
7 & 8 & 9 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Result}
\label{tab:a}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Note: The use of `\caption` indicates that you're placing your `tabular` inside a (floating) `table` environment; in that case, I recommend to [replace the `center` environment with `\centering`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/should-i-use-center-or-centering-for-figures-and-tables).

Comment: could'nt vote up ! but thanks :)

Comment: @anon You're welcome -- and you may add your upvote once you reach 15 rep points. ;-)